# Read yahoo RSS with Python

Tags: python, rss, python-requests-html

i am trying to parse a [yahoo rss feed](https://finance.yahoo.com/rss/) containing the following item in order to put all the data into a pandas dataframe

```
<item>
   <title>Retirement-Reform Bill Could Slash Taxes</title>
   <link>
   https://www.thestreet.com/retirement/secure-2-new-retirement-reform-bill-could-slash-taxes?puc=yahoo&cm_ven=YAHOO&yptr=yahoo
   </link>
   <source url="http://www.thestreet.com/">TheStreet.com</source>
</item>
```

The code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from requests_html import HTML
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
response = session.get(url)
with response as r:
     items = r.html.find("item", first=False)  
     for item in items:
         print(item.html)
         link = item.find('link')
```

link now contains `[<Element 'link' >]` and although i checked with dir(link) how to access the Element i didn't found a way.

Then i have seen i kind of conversion using `item.html`

I am getting a `<link/>` instead of `<link> ... </link>`

```
<item><title>Retirement-Reform Bill Could Slash Taxes</title><link/>https://www.thestreet.com/retirement/secure-2-new-retirement-reform-bill-could-slash-taxes?puc=yahoo&amp;cm_ven=YAHOO&amp;yptr=yahoo <pubdate>2022-03-29T16:22:00Z</pubdate><source url="http://www.thestreet.com/">TheStreet.com</source><guid ispermalink="false">secure-2-new-retirement-reform-bill-could-slash-taxes?puc=yahoo&amp;cm_ven=YAHOO&amp;yptr=yahoo</guid><content height="86" url="https://s.yimg.com/uu/api/res/1.2/C_nEPpNu9gDsTyEFMP4_Gw--~B/aD00MDA7dz02MDA7YXBwaWQ9eXRhY2h5b24-/https://media.zenfs.com/en/thestreet.com/2f7c38768e85cdba72bfed65497673a6" width="130"/><credit role="publishing company"/></item>
```

**any hints how to access the link Element?**

Answer (score 0):

Consider treat the result as `string` and split the value as follows:

```
# Here you're getting the full element.
link = item.find('link')

# Get the link only: 
link = link.split('<link/>')[1].split('<')[0].strip()
```

Prints:

```
https://www.thestreet.com/retirement/secure-2-new-retirement-reform-bill-could-slash-taxes?puc=yahoo&amp;cm_ven=YAHOO&amp;yptr=yahoo
```